# Why was this question on buying a SIM card at Woodlands checkpoint in Singapore closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I see many questions about buying SIM cards at places typically frequented by travelers, such as:

- [Is it possible to get and activate a SIM card after 23:00 in Tallinn (Airport)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/101002/1810)
- [Can I get a Mexican SIM card in Cancun Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110258/1810)
- [Is it useful to buy a prepaid SIM card at HK airport but use it in the mainland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/110428/1810)
- [Where can I get a SIM card at the Hyderabad (Telangana, India) airport, or somewhere on the way to Banjara Hills?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/121245/1810)
- [Where to buy a SIM card at Ben Gurion airport, Israel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/128509/1810)
- [Is it possible to buy US sim card at Columbus airport, Ohio](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/138813/1810)
- [Is it possible for a tourist to buy a SIM card at Beijing airport (terminal 2)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/147591/1810)
- [Can one purchase a SIM card at Yangon International Airport (RNG) between 1 AM and 8 AM?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/148364/1810)
- [Can one purchase a SIM card at Bagan Nyaung-U Airport (NYU)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/148474/1810)
- [Is it possible to buy a SIM card in a transit zone of Doha airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159028/1810)
- [In Paris, can one purchase pre-paid sim card upon arrival at CDG airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21572/1810)
- [Where to buy a SIM card in Cape Town](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21580/1810)
- [Buying a SIM card at Heathrow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3758/1810)
- [Buying a SIM card on arrival in Amsterdam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38127/1810)
- [Prepaid phone number provider in Sydney / Brisbane airports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64995/1810)
- [Where to buy a TIM simcard in Malpensa airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79057/1810)
- [Is it possible to buy a SIM card at Lyon airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79292/1810)
- [Can I get SIM card at Pudong International Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79962/1810)
- [Where to buy a prepaid SIM card at Grenoble airport or Alpe d'Huez?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/85346/1810)
- [Is there a store selling T-Mobile SIM cards in Houston's IAH International Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/87077/1810)
- [Can I get a local sim card at London Ontario International Airport (YXU)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/99611/1810)

They are all upvoted and none of them got closed. I didn't cherry pick, I just looked at the first few questions listed on [cellphones](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellphones).

Then [Where can one buy a SIM card at Woodlands checkpoint in Singapore?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185057/1810) got closed. Why?

Comment: You know the answer, someone voted to close, others followed. Please vote to reopen, asking here is only useful in that I see it.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, yes just to increase visibility and if I had missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question [Where can one buy a SIM card at Woodlands checkpoint in Singapore?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/185057/1810) was reopened. I think it's good to keep this meta question as it gives some concrete examples of empirically acceptable list questions about buying SIM cards.